# Sorting an array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, object, qsort

I'm trying to make an alphabetically sorted array of objects from a class that contains also another int variable, but I can't make work qsort function properly.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp (char **str1 , char **str2 )
{
  return strcmp(*str1,*str2);
}

class myclass
{
 int id;
 char text[50];
 public: 
  void add(char a[], int i) { strcpy(text,a); id=i; }
  void show(void) { std::cout<<text<<std::endl; }
};


int main (void)
{
  myclass * myobject[4];
  myobject[0] = new myclass;
  myobject[1] = new myclass;
  myobject[2] = new myclass;
  myobject[3] = new myclass;
  myobject[0]->add("zoom",1);
  myobject[1]->add("zoo",2);
  myobject[2]->add("animal",3);
  myobject[3]->add("bull",4);

  qsort (myobject,4,sizeof(char *), (int (*)(const void *, const void *)) cmp);

  for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) 
    myobject[i]->show();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And `qsort()` actually is?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A standard C/C++ library function.

Comment: Why don't use a `std` container instead of an array. Then you could use `std::sort`, or use a container that keeps the data sorted all the time.

Comment: You can use std::sort on an array, too.

Comment: What do you think `(int (*)(const void *, const void *)) cmp` does? You don't cast functions like this. You have to actually write a function that takes two `const void*` arguments and returns `int`. ...But, still, usage of `std::sort` is recommended anyway in C++ over `qsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your comparison function needs to be able to access the private member *text* of *myclass*.

You could either make *text* public or add

```
friend int cmp (const void *, const void*);
```

in the class definition.

Second, your comparison function is wrong. It takes pointers to the members of the array to be sorted. You should write it like this:

```
int cmp (const void *ptr1 , const void *ptr2)
{
    myclass *m1 = *(myclass**)ptr1;
    myclass *m2 = *(myclass**)ptr2;

    return strcmp(m1->text, m2->text);
}
```

Comment: That's just I needed to make it all work. Thank you for your friend function code tip, I forgot about it!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your code looks like a warped version of C code, with just enough C++ "sprinkled" in to keep it from working with a C compiler. At least IMO, this gives pretty much the worst of both worlds--it removes most of the best features of C, and the best features of C++. If you're going to write C++, write C++, not warped C.

To create and sort a collection of objects in C++, you should probably write the code more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class myclass
{
    int id;
    std::string text;
public:
    myclass(std::string const &a, int i) : id(i), text(a) {}

    bool operator<(myclass const &other) {
        return text < other.text;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, myclass const &m) {
        return std::cout << m.text << "\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<myclass> myobjects{
        { "zoom", 1 },
        { "zoo", 2 },
        { "animal", 3 },
        { "bull", 4 }
    };

    std::sort(myobjects.begin(), myobjects.end());

    for (auto const &o : myobjects)
        std::cout << o;
}
```

At least in my opinion, this is quite a bit simpler and easier to understand. It doesn't leak memory. If (for example) we added another item to the collection of items, we wouldn't have to rewrite other code to accommodate that.

Probably more importantly than any of the above, at least for me this leads to faster, easier, more bug-free development. Just for example, the code above was bug-free (worked correctly) the first time it compiled. Other than fixing a couple of obvious typos (e.g., I'd mis-typed `operator` as `opertor`) it compiled and ran exactly as I originally typed it in. As a slight bonus, it probably runs faster than the C-like version. With only 4 items, the difference in speed won't be noticeable, but if you had (for example) thousands of items, `std::sort` would almost certainly be substantially faster than `qsort` (two to three times as fast is fairly common).

Comment: Yes, you are true, but I have to compile my file in Dev-C++, which uses outdated libraries and that's why I was trying to use qsort. Thanks for your code, I'll keep it for future programs!

Comment: @DvD23: If you're using a compiler so old it's really missing `std::sort`, the only reasonable response is to update the compiler. Anything released within the last 20 years (or so) should have `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function is wrong. It receives a pointer to each array element, which is a pointer to `myclass`, not the `text`.You also shouldn't cast the function pointer when calling `qsort`, you should cast the arguments in the comparison function.

```
int cmp (void *a, void *b) {
    myclass **c1 = (myclass **)a;
    myclass **c2 = (myclass **)b;
    return strcmp((*c1)->text, (*c2)->text);
}
```

Comment: @NicholasM I mentioned that in a comment.